# Web View in a Fragment - Android

Tags: android

How can I load a web view into a fragment?

I've tried the obvious but it opens a new browser and my nav disappears:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle saved)
{

View mainView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_a, group, false);
    myWebView = (WebView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
   myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.bbc.co.uk");
    return mainView;

}
```

I've also search stack overflow and the web, tried some of the examples but they do not work either, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often had such situation, when after redirect page was opened in an external browser. Try to set `WebViewClient` with overriden [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) method which returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return(inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_fragment, container, false));
  }

  public void loadUrl(String url) {
    ((WebView)(getView().findViewById(R.id.browser))).loadUrl(url);
  }
}
```

Comment: There are no examples of how to use this.

Comment: Plus it requires API 11, I want to go down to 7.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a new WebViewClient to you webView will let the WebView handle urls internally.

```
webViewer = (WebView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
webViewer.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

this is supported by the documentation: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html